# C++ ofstream doesn't change mtime

Tags: c++, touch, fstream, ofstream

Basically I want to do the same thing as the system call touch (create the file if it doesn't exist, update its modification timestamp if it does).

```
std::string file = ...;
std::ofstream(file.c_str(), std::ios::app);
```

This will create the file if it doesn't exist. but it won't change the modification time.

```
std::string file = ...;
std::ofstream(file.c_str(), std::ios::out);
```

This will create it if it doesn't exist, it'll update the modification time if it does, but it'll also truncate the file, if it exists.

So how do I touch a file?

Comment: This won't be defined by the C++ language itself. You can be sure there are platforms out there where this program works as intended, so we need to know more specifically what you're using.

Comment: the ofstream class if for reading/writing files. It won't offer any file attribute modification function. You will need a system call based on your platform

Comment: This may help you http://www.koders.com/c/fid96336B4591FD0C5D2C4DADA2D264D3A04F21A934.aspx

Comment: So, `utime(2)` seems to be the Posix answer...

Comment: On a POSIX.1-2008 system, you want [utimensat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utimes.html).

Comment: If somebody would write "utime()" as an answer (instead of a comment), I'd accept it (works on Windows too)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kerrek SB has posted the solution, but unfortunately in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677200/c-ofstream-doesnt-change-mtime#comment-13854978) rather than an answer (I'd rather accept his answer).

I've had success with [utime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utime.2.html):

```
#include <utime.h>
...
std::string path = "/path/to/my/file";
bool success = !utime(path.c_str(), 0);
```

David Schwartz [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677200/c-ofstream-doesnt-change-mtime#comment-13855059) [utimensat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimensat.2.html) for nanosecond precision.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure C++ version of `touch` that does not need POSIX:

```
// touch.cc
// C++ version of 'touch' utility.

#include <iostream>                    // std::cout
#include <fstream>                     // std::fstream

static bool touchFile(char const *fname)
{
  // Open the file for writing.  This fails if the file does not exist.
  std::fstream stream(fname, std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
  if (stream.fail()) {
    // File does not exist, or a permission error.  Try creating the file.
    stream.open(fname, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    return stream.good();
  }

  // Read the first character.
  int ch = stream.get();
  if (ch == std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
    // The file is empty.  Reopen with truncation to bump mtime.
    stream.close();
    stream.open(fname, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    return stream.good();
  }

  // Rewind the write head.
  stream.seekp(0);
  if (stream.fail()) {
    return false;
  }

  // Write that same character.  A write is necessary to update the
  // modification time.
  stream.put(ch);
  return stream.good();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2) {
    std::cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " filename\n";
    return 2;
  }

  char const *fname = argv[1];
  if (!touchFile(fname)) {
    std::cerr << "failed to update: " << fname << "\n";
    return 2;
  }

  return 0;
}


// EOF
```

The main idea is to read the first character and then overwrite it with itself to force the timestamp to be updated.  It also handles the special cases of a non-existent file or one that exists but is empty.

Testing this program:

```
$ rm tmp                               # start with no file

$ ./touch.exe tmp                      # create empty file

$ ls -l --full-time tmp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Scott None 0 2022-08-19 01:42:55.410168800 -0700 tmp*

$ ./touch.exe tmp                      # update empty file

$ ls -l --full-time tmp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Scott None 0 2022-08-19 01:43:04.442676700 -0700 tmp*

$ echo x > tmp                         # now file has data

$ ls -l --full-time tmp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Scott None 2 2022-08-19 01:43:14.374642800 -0700 tmp*

$ ./touch.exe tmp                      # update it

$ ls -l --full-time tmp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Scott None 2 2022-08-19 01:43:20.494178000 -0700 tmp*

$ chmod 000 tmp                        # clear permissions

$ ./touch.exe tmp                      # fails as expected
failed to update: tmp
Exit 2

$ ls -l --full-time tmp
---------- 1 Scott None 2 2022-08-19 01:43:20.494178000 -0700 tmp

$ chmod 644 tmp                        # restore permissions

$ ./touch.exe tmp                      # can update again

$ ls -l --full-time tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 Scott None 2 2022-08-19 01:43:52.012350700 -0700 tmp
```